# Creating a dll providing two modules under one namespace

Tags: c#, .net, dll, f#, interop

Given the below project definition.

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Compile Include="Program.fs" />
    <Compile Include="Api.fs" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="OfficeIMO.Word" Version="0.11.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.fs contains a module "WordProcessingML" in the namespace docx.
Api.fs contains a module "Api" in the namespace docx. This code builds
and publishes to a dll file. The problem is when I try using the resulting
dll file from another C# project, only WordProcessingML and not Api seems
to be visible. My first question is what should I instead be doing to
use the Api from the C# project, my second question is what am I doing
(my current assumption is that the dll is being built with only the first
module found not including the next).

I have to this moment spent hours searching how to use the second module with the first.
The reason I'm organizing the code this way is that I'm following [this gist](https://gist.github.com/swlaschin/2d3e75a2ff4a87112c19309c86e0dd41). Also please
alert me if I'm following what is an outdated guide.

```
// Per this gist https://gist.github.com/swlaschin/2d3e75a2ff4a87112c19309c86e0dd41
namespace docx
module Api =
    type Run = docx.WordProcessingML.Run
    type DocumentPart = docx.WordProcessingML.DocumentPart
    let Save(document: docx.WordProcessingML.Document): string =
        if isNull (box document) then nullArg "document"
        docx.WordProcessingML.Save document
    let Paragraph(runs: Run seq): docx.WordProcessingML.Paragraph =
        if isNull (box runs) then nullArg "runs"
        List.ofSeq runs
    let Document(path: string, parts: DocumentPart seq): docx.WordProcessingML.Document =
        if isNull (box path) then nullArg "path"
        if isNull (box parts) then nullArg "parts"
        {path=path; parts=(List.ofSeq parts)}
    let IntoPart(paragraph: docx.WordProcessingML.Paragraph): Result<DocumentPart, string>=
        if isNull (box paragraph) then
            Error("Null Parameter")
        else
            Ok(docx.WordProcessingML.Par paragraph)
```

Comment: Can you show the contents of `Api.fs`?

Comment: I have added the contents of Api.fs.

Comment: Are you sure you're looking at the right build artifact? Can you change something in `Program.fs` and see if that gets reflected at the point of consumption?

Comment: I deleted the entire bin folder and invoked "dotnet publish" again, it works just fine now.

Not sure why it wasn't updating, I deleted from file explorer and up-arrowed...
This question didn't need asked. Thanks